# How to find the highest value number from list of items?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
List<int> num = new List<int>();
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.white;

        scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, true,true,
            GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true), GUILayout.Height(position.height));

        foreach (KeyValuePair<GameObject, string> pair in dictio)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(pair.Key, typeof(GameObject), true);
            num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(pair.Value).Length);
            

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
        GUILayout.EndScrollView();

        window.maxSize = new Vector2(num[], position.height);
    }
```

after the loop I want to find the highest value from the List num and set it as the window width size.

Comment: use [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max) ?

Comment: Or why even use a list for this? you could simply have a `var maxWidth = 0;` and then for each iteration do `maxWidth = Mathf.Max(maxWidth, EditorGUILayout.TextField(pair.Value).Length);` without the need for iterating yet another list ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `int max = num.Max();`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use `.Sort()` or `.OrderBy(x => x)` or even `.OrderByDescending(x => x)` and get the highest value that way?

For example, you could do

```
int width = num.OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault()`
```

or

```
int width = num.Max()
```

or

```
num.Sort();
num.Reverse();
int width = num.FirstOrDefault();
```